# Using password character "*" in InputBox

Tags: vb.net

I want to use `*` character in inputbox but an error prompts

```
conversion from "*" to string invalid
```

How can I make my inputbox hide typed text into password characters?

Here is my code

```
Dim value As String
value = InputBox("Security Check", " Enter password", "*")

If value = "123456" Then
    numr.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If this is WinForms, don't use the InputBox.  Create a form with a TextBox and set the Password character property.

Comment: Correct. You can't use an InputBox with a password-character.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the built in Function InputBox. Ths value you are setting "*" is the defaultvalue of that function. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z0ak68w(v=vs.90).aspx

Here is something you could do. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?627996-Accepting-password-characters-for-InputBox-function

Answer (score 1):

You have to define it yourself  this is the Code I wrote to make a custom Password Input Box I defined it as a class and then inherited the form class and gave it custom properties  By doing this I have created a property that determines if access is granted or not.  you can create encryption and communicate with Database for password retrieval but this simply shows how to use the custom control.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim test As New CustomForm("workflow")

    Public Class CustomForm
        Inherits Form
        Property SecretPassword As String
        Property GrantAccess As Boolean
        Sub New(Password As String)
            GrantAccess = False
            Me.SecretPassword = Password
            Dim lbl As New Label
            lbl.Text = "Password"
            Me.Controls.Add(lbl)
            Me.Text = "***PASSWORD INPUT REQUIRED***"
            Dim frmSZ As New Size(400, 100)
            Me.Size = frmSZ
            Dim IBox As New TextBox
            AddHandler IBox.KeyDown, AddressOf TextBox1_KeyDown
            Dim ibox20 As New Point(100, 0)
            IBox.Location = ibox20
            IBox.PasswordChar = "*"
            Me.Controls.Add(IBox)
            Me.Show()
        End Sub
        Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.KeyCode.Enter Then
                Try
                    Dim passswordInput As String = sender.text
                    If passswordInput = Me.SecretPassword Then
                        GrantAccess = True
                        Me.Dispose()
                    Else
                        MsgBox("Sorry the password you entered is not correct please try again. The password is case sensitive make sure your caps lock is not on.")

                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox(test.GrantAccess)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I started with this implementation, then found another implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959649/password-message-box-in-vb) that worked better for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `InputBox` function doesn't have this parameter. VB.Net is reading your `"*"` as the value for the `DefaultResponse` parameter, or what `value` will equal if the user just accepts the default entry.

As a matter of fact, `InputBox`, while still found in the VisualBasic Namespace, is not considered up to date coding practice since 2003, but is still used by many who are or were accustomed to VB6 (including myself). It's most recent entry in the MSDN Visual Basic Reference is for the 2008 version of Visual Studio, and is not found in the current (2017) Visual Basic Language Reference.

The standard way of using an `*` or other password character in .Net, is to use a Windows Forms TextBox, and then use either the `PasswordChar` or `UseSystemPasswordChar` properties to change the nature of the TextBox inside the Form. These can be accessed in the in the Form Design Properties window, or as properties of the TextBox within your code.

Comment: For reviewers in the Late Answer Queue: The question still comes up in Google and continues to have viewers, yet the answers singularly are insufficient. Of the two currently upvoted, one has screenshots and a dead link only, the other explains well the misunderstanding behind the function but links to a forum thread that, while the answer can be gleaned there with some effort, violates the 'Be Nice' policy. The other answer seems to have good code, but is Not An Answer. Feel free to delete comment after passage through Review.