# Password Message box in VB

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

When a user does something specific such as saving data. I need a messagebox to appear asking the user to enter their password within that messagebox in order to validate the data.

Is it possible? And if so , how ?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. How does one do it? Depends on your code. Obviously. Perhaps you should hire someone to do this change...

Comment: Ok thanks, at least I know that it is possible. I just need to find out how to do it. I have looked around for customised messageboxes I haven't found a solution yet

Comment: To approximate the behavior of a MessageBox with one or more textboxes you need to write your own form and show it using the ShowDialog method. You also need to provide some kind of value passing between forms using public properties. The full answer is too broad.

Comment: Use an InputBox this would be great for your needs as it returns input from the user.

Comment: Check below for a custom password dialog box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to make your own DialogBoxes.

Example:

```vb
    Option Strict On
    Option Explicit On
    Option Infer Off
    Public Class Form1
        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim pwD As New PasswordDialogBox
            If pwD.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                MessageBox.Show("The user entered the following password: '" & pwD.Password & "'", "Password Confirmed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("The user cancelled.", "User Cancel", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
    Public Class PasswordDialogBox
        Inherits Form
        Friend WithEvents tbPassword As New TextBox With {.PasswordChar = "*"c, .Parent = Me}
        Friend WithEvents Label1 As New Label With {.Parent = Me}
        Friend WithEvents okButton As New Button With {.Text = "OK", .Parent = Me}
        Friend Shadows WithEvents cancelButton As New Button With {.Text = "Cancel", .Parent = Me}
        Public Property Password As String
        Sub New()
            Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow
            Me.Size = New Size(200, 150)
            Me.Text = "Enter Password"
            tbPassword.Left = Me.ClientRectangle.Width \ 2 - tbPassword.ClientRectangle.Width \ 2
            tbPassword.Top = Me.ClientRectangle.Height \ 2 - tbPassword.ClientRectangle.Height \ 2
            Label1.AutoSize = True
            Label1.Text = "Please enter a password"
            Label1.Left = (Me.ClientRectangle.Width \ 2) - (Label1.ClientRectangle.Width \ 2)
            okButton.Left = Me.ClientRectangle.Width - 5 - okButton.ClientRectangle.Width
            okButton.Top = Me.ClientRectangle.Height - 5 - okButton.Height
            cancelButton.Left = 5
            cancelButton.Top = Me.ClientRectangle.Height - 5 - cancelButton.Height
        End Sub
        Private Sub okButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles okButton.Click
            If PasswordMeetsCriteria(tbPassword.Text) Then
                Me.Password = tbPassword.Text
                Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Password is invalid, please re-enter your password or cancel.", "Invalid Password", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End If
        End Sub
        Function PasswordMeetsCriteria(password As String) As Boolean
            Dim validCharacters As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`1234567890-=~!@#$%^&*()_+,./;'[]\<>?:""{}"
            For Each c As Char In password
                If validCharacters.IndexOf(c) = -1 Then Return False
            Next
            Return True
        End Function
        Private Sub cancelButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cancelButton.Click
            Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: Awsome thanks , I will  have a look at the code and see what I can extract from it in order to implement it into my system

Comment: You're welcome! Let me know if you have a question about it :-)